# Join two .xoj files

Tags: pdf

If i annotate a pdf with xournal and then annotate the same pdf on another pc, also with xournal, is it possible to join these two .xoj files ?
I tried to google the problem, but found nothing about this.

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not need to edit the annotations later on**, the easiest way is to export one of the xoj files to a new pdf and use this as the background for the other one.